# How do I do cv2.min operation in skimage?

Tags: opencv, scikit-image

How do I do cv2.min operation in skimage?
Is there a method for that in skimage or do I need to write it?

Answer (score 1):

```
masked = np.minimum.reduce([img1,img2])
```